# What is wrong with the following instructions?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips64

Stuck on a question while looking over my past exam papers. The question reads 'What, if anything, is wrong with the following instructions?'

```
.text
   dadd r2,r0,10
   j r3
   dsub r4,r1,N(r0)
```

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on which assembler you're using. But if we assume that you're using an assembler that looks at the instructions strictly as-is:

```
dadd r2,r0,10
```

The `dadd` instructions takes three registers as its operands. For the operands `r2,r0,10` you would use `daddi` (doubleword add immediate).

---

```
j r3
```

The `j` instruction expects an absolute address (i.e. `j some_label`). For register-indirect jumps you'd use the `jr` instruction.

---

```
dsub r4,r1,N(r0)
```

Like `dadd`, `dsub` also takes three registers as its operands. As far as I know there's no variant of `dsub` that accepts a memory location as one of its operands. This instruction would have to be split in two (e.g. `ld r4,N(r0)`, followed by `dsub r4,r1,r4`).